# Редакция предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Как отредактировать следующее предложение?

А тех, кто готов менять будущее, по определению мало — социологи говорят 1:1000, а то и 1:10 000.

1. А тех, кто готов менять будущее, по определению мало — социологи говорят, 
   1:1000, а то и 1:10 000.
2. А тех, кто готов менять будущее, по определению мало. Социологи говорят —  1:1000, а то и 1:10 000.
3. А тех, кто готов менять будущее, по определению мало. Социологи говорят:   1:1000, а то и 1:10 000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все три варианта допустимы. Тире в первом случае уместно как интонационный знак и зрительный знак, разделяющий две части осложненного предложения.

Тире во втором случае на месте, на месте двоеточия - это относительно новая практика, но она достаточно устоявшаяся, где-то даже Розенталь отмечал еще при жизни. Используется, когда можно двояко трактовать второю часть - и как раскрытие смысла первой, и как самостоятельную конструкцию.

Но при всем том, Лично мне нравится третий вариант, с точкой и двоеточием. ))
Точка там не просто для того, чтобы избежать сомнений в правильности оформления. Она стилистически оправдана, так смотрится лучше. И двоеточие в этом случае тоже смотрится лучше.

Что же касается четвертого варианта, shampar'а, то по мне он ничем не лучше даже первых двух "авторских"

Answer (score 0):

А таких, кто готов менять будущее, по определению мало — социологи говорят: один на тысячу, а то и на десятки тысяч.

Comment: А тире допустимо?

Comment: Поддерживаю по словам, по знакам затрудняюсь. Только зачем Вы заменили "тех" на "таких"? По-моему, было лучше.

Comment: Так показалось вначале, сейчас разницы не вижу. О тире: разрывать на два предложения — не такое большое предложение, но большой тормоз. Вторая часть есть аргументация первой части, которая есть вывод, утверждение.

Comment: Я имею в виду: двоеточие перед 1:1000 кажется не смотрится, запятую нельзя (?), остается вариант 2 - с тире. По правилам он допустим?

Comment: Не поняла про точку с запятой... Лучше, чем тире?

Comment: Можно ";"?! Да ладно...

Comment: Можно и двоеточие, можно и тчк/зпт, можно зпт, но лучше связки (визуальной в т.ч.), а это части целого, чем тире не подобрать. Если есть опасения правки третьим лицом, то поставьте зпт+тире.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Возможны варианты:  А тех, кто готов менять будущее, по определению мало.Социологи говорят: 1:1000, а то и 1:10 000.
А тех, кто готов менять будущее, по определению мало. Социологи говорят, 1:1000, а то и 1:10 000.

Вариант с запятой, конечно, возможен, но в этом случае, он менее формальный. Вариант с тире не подходит потому,что после него предложение приобретает пояснительно-уточняющие значение. Но после "по определению мало" вряд ли можно вставить "а именно".

Answer (score 0):

Я бы отредактировал следующим образом:

"А тех, кто готов менять будущее, по определению мало: по мнению социологов, таковых один на тысячу, а то и один на все десять тысяч".